# Looking for semantic hierarchy, tagset or connected active research

Tags: semantics, resource-request

I am working on building a semantic markup for my native language and I have bumped into the fact that ready semantic hierarchy or tagset is a very scarce resource.

What I am looking for is something like that:

```
- CONCERETE
  - LIFE
    - HUMAN
      - POWER
        :: king, prime-minister, president, etc
    ...
- ABSTRACT
  - EVENT
    :: wedding, inauguration
...
```

(example are just for illustrative purpose only, I need structure only)

There are, of course, some classical works like Roget's Thesaurus, but it has been developed long long ago and I am looking for something more contemporary.

Comment: Are you aware of the [semantic web stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_ontology).

Comment: Interestingly, a reference to http://schema.org/ is missing in the semantic web wikipedia page.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_learning

Answer (score 3):

ConceptNet has the "is a type of" relations stored, for example:
http://conceptnet.io/c/en/king

They've preloaded many great sources (Cyc, dbpedia, wordnet, etc). The issue is, the words aren't tagged by a word-sense key. So, using the "king" example, the kb doesn't distinguish between a 'monarch' or a 'chess piece'.

Some people like the type system in Freeebase or dbpedia. You can find the list here: https://www.textrazor.com/types

And I'll leave the Roget outline here for other people,  as a resource:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Outline_of_Roget%27s_Thesaurus

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a  [Wordnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet) is a resource that can help you as a starter. I do not know what language is in your mind, but there is the [Open Multilingual Wordnet](http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/) project hosted by Nanyang Technological University (Singapore) that may even cover the language of your choice.